# Get category tree by path and sort order

Tags: mysql, sql

My category structure is shown below. My purpose is to get category structure with single query.
I sort my table by path and I get category tree.

**sort_order** : Indicates sort order between categories with same level

[image]

When I run query

```
SELECT * FROM category order by path;
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

**But result must be as shown below**  because sort_order of Electronic is 1 and this is less than sort_order value of Computer category 2

```
 - ELectronic 
 - - TV 
 - - - LCD 
 - - - - LED LCD 
 - Computer 
 - - Laptop
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** added SQL Fiddle stuff

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a39211/2)

**MySQL 5.5.28 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sortorder` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `category`
--

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `parent_id`, `label`, `level`, `path`, `sortorder`) VALUES
(0, 0, '', 0, '', 0),
(2, 0, 'Computer', 1, '.2.', 2),
(3, 0, 'Electronic', 1, '.3.', 1),
(4, 3, 'TV', 2, '.3.4.', 3),
(5, 2, 'Laptop', 2, '.2.5.', 4),
(6, 7, 'LED LCD', 4, '.3.4.7.6.', 5),
(7, 4, 'LCD', 3, '.3.4.7', 5);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  (
    SELECT group_concat( cast( g.sortorder AS char ) ORDER BY g.path ) AS gso
    FROM category AS g
    WHERE c.path LIKE concat( g.path, '%' )
  ) AS grsortorder, c. *
FROM `category` AS c
ORDER BY grsortorder
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a39211/2/0)**:

```
| GRSORTORDER | ID | PARENT_ID |      LABEL | LEVEL |      PATH | SORTORDER |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|           0 |  0 |         0 |            |     0 |           |         0 |
|         0,1 |  3 |         0 | Electronic |     1 |       .3. |         1 |
|       0,1,3 |  4 |         3 |         TV |     2 |     .3.4. |         3 |
|     0,1,3,5 |  7 |         4 |        LCD |     3 |    .3.4.7 |         5 |
|   0,1,3,5,5 |  6 |         7 |    LED LCD |     4 | .3.4.7.6. |         5 |
|         0,2 |  2 |         0 |   Computer |     1 |       .2. |         2 |
|       0,2,4 |  5 |         2 |     Laptop |     2 |     .2.5. |         4 |
```

Comment: @faridmovsumov [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a39211/2) check this please

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But problem is that if we add 10 to path your algorithm doesn't work properly.

Comment: @faridmovsumov, give example please

Answer (score 0):

See if that works:

```
SELECT * FROM category order by level, sort_order, path;
```

**RESULT :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer.I have added result of your query to your answer. This is not result that I need

Comment: That is possible to solve with CONNECT BY, but unfortunatelly MySQL does not offer support to that clause. See if that blog post helps you: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: Tiago César Oliveira I am trying to understand this but it seems doesn't solve my problem... I can't adopt it to my problem